# Creatin a custom web page

Tags: html

I am new to Web page design and creation - but I need to create a Web Page for my project. I am also a little familiar with HTML / JS and Jquery. But I don't think creating a web page is that easy. Looking at different web site pages, I feel more compelled to create a tabs menu graphical page with images and formatted content in it.

Is there a tool or easy way for novice to quickly build a web page without bothering about HTML and other stuff. It would automatically create CSS for me and ready to use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: Microsoft Expression Web, Adobe Dreamweaver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get) html editor.  There's a ton of tools around for that.  Just search Google.  Keep in mind that the results you get from something like that are usually not quite as good as a hand-crafted site as far generating clean html/css.  Unfortunately, I don't have any recommendations as to what the bests ones are for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: Use Wordpress or some other pre-made CMS.

Comment: But issue with pre-made pages I found is that it's difficult to customize my way completely. Is there a tool that produces HTML / CSS and other thing and provides a UI to me just place the objects

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it too.